# How can I see a list of all users and the roles assigned to them in Azure?

Tags: azure

I am an Azure Administrator.

I would like to know if there is an easy way of showing a list of users in Azure and the role assignments they have against which Subscriptions, User Groups and Resources?

Basically, i'd like a list of all role assignments people have on anything.

Conversely i'd accept a list of every Resource Group and Resource in a Subscription and list the role assignments on them.

Doesn't sound like a big ask?

What's the simplest way of doing this?

-- Lee

Comment: Azure Portal has this functionality. Have you tried it? Just go to Subscription -> IAM -> Role Assignments.

Comment: Doesn't that only shows me the role assignments on the Subscription.. not child Resource Groups or Resources? I'd like to see role assignments on all Resource Groups and Resources as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you can check it in the portal directly. Navigate to the resource/resource group/subscription in the portal -> `Access control (IAM)` -> `Role assignments`, you can filter with the parameters you want.

[image]

Or you can use the Azure powershell [`Get-AzRoleAssignment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.Resources/Get-azRoleAssignment?view=azps-3.1.0) or [`REST API`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/roleassignments), it depends on your requirement.

**Sample**:

1.You have a list of ObjectIds of the users, you can use the script as below.

```
[string[]]$ids = "5c2cf3xxx99e895","44b8xxxx0cd8","b2a9xxxxc34e"
foreach($id in $ids){
    Get-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId $id
}
```

[image]

2.You have the SignInNames of the users.

```
[string[]]$names = "xxxx@xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com","xxxx@xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com","xxxx@xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
foreach($name in $names){
    Get-AzRoleAssignment -SignInName $name
}
```

[image]

### Update:

**Note:** The role assignment in Azure is inheritable, e.g. If you add the role assignment for a user in the `subscription` scope, when you list the role assignments in a `resource group`, the role assignment of the user will also be listed. The same logic for resource groups and resources in the group.

1.You have the SignInNames of the users, want to get the role assignments of all the resources in the subscription.

```
[string[]]$names = "xxxx@xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com","xxxx@xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com","xxxx@xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
$rids = (Get-AzResource).ResourceId
foreach($rid in $rids){
    foreach($name in $names){
        Get-AzRoleAssignment -Scope $rid -SignInName $name 
    }   
}
```

2.You have the SignInNames of the users, want to get the role assignments of all the resources in a specific resource group.

```
[string[]]$names = "xxxx@xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com","xxxx@xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com","xxxx@xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
$rids = (Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName <group-name>).ResourceId
foreach($rid in $rids){
    foreach($name in $names){
        Get-AzRoleAssignment -Scope $rid -SignInName $name 
    }   
}
```

3.You have the SignInNames of the users, want to get the role assignments of all the resource groups in the subscription.

```
[string[]]$names = "xxxx@xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com","xxxx@xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com","xxxx@xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
$gids = (Get-AzResourceGroup).ResourceId
foreach($gid in $gids){
    foreach($name in $names){
        Get-AzRoleAssignment -Scope $gid -SignInName $name 
    }   
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried the Subscriptions -> Access control (IAM) -> Role assignments but it does not show all role assignments on child Resource Groups and Resources.

Your script solves half my question.. 

It would completely answer my question if it could get the list of subscriptions, resource groups and resources then iterate over them and output the role assignments.

Comment: @LeeEnglestone Actually they are the same logic, just change the script to meet your own requirements, you could check my update.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
    
    
subscriptions_list=($(az account list --all --query "[].id" -o table  | grep -vi "resul\|--"))
    
#echo "These subscriptions are linked to Azure Account: $subscriptions_list"
    

    
echo ""
    
echo "Below is the list of <USERS> with direct role assignments to subscriptions"
    
echo ""
    

    
# Listing "Users" with direct tole assignments to subscriptions
    

    
for subscription in "${subscriptions_list[@]}"; do
    
 echo "************************************************************************************"
    
 echo "Direct Role Assignments(s) for subscription id: $subscription"
    
 echo ""
    
 az role assignment list --subscription $subscription --query "[?principalType=='User'].{Role:roleDefinitionName,Email:principalName}" -o table
    
 echo ""
    
done
```

The "az account list" az cli command saves the output (list of subscriptions) in a variable. Then a for loop iterates through these subscriptions one by one, listing their owners (of type "User"). Please ask if it's unclear.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: The "az account list" az cli command saves the output (list of subscriptions) in a variable. Then a for loop iterates through these subscriptions one by one, listing their owners (of type "User"). Please ask if it's unclear.

Comment: Thanks @SvenEberth. New to StackOverflow.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button and add the description to your answer, not as comment.